# Specifying shared libraries in ld.so.conf.d has lower priority than default

Tags: raspbian, shared-libraries

I've compiled openssl 1.1.0g manually and when run

`ldd $(which openssl)` it returns:

```
...
libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libssl.so.1.1
libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.1
...
```

However, I want to point both of them to `/usr/local/lib`.
On ubuntu 16.04, I solved it by creating file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/openssl.conf` with `/usr/local/lib`, `sudo ldconfig` and it worked. However, on raspbian it doesn't seem to make any difference.

I can make it work by editing `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/arm-linux-gnueabihf`, like this:

```
#Multiarch support
/lib/arm-gnueabihf
/usr/local/lib # ADDED THIS LINE
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

So my question is, if its okay to keep this solution? Or there could be some problems in the future? If not, what is the proper way of doing this?

Thanks!

Edit:

`sudo ldconfig -v` tells that both `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/openssl.conf` and `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/arm-linux-gnueabihf.conf` are loaded. The problem is with priority! On ubuntu, custom `*.conf` go first, but on raspbian priority is given to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/arm-linux-gnueabihf.conf` first. Is it expected behaviour?

Comment: The files are most likely parsed in alphabetical order, try adding a prefix, for example "00-", to your custom configuration file (00-openssl.conf) so that it is used before arm-linux-gnueabihf.conf

Comment: @onion You are right, it is based on the alphabetical order. Thanks man! Now it makes sense, on ubuntu it was x86-... so it was lower priority.